# Is it normal to have duplicate /var mount if using docker?

Tags: rhel, mount, docker, xfs

[image]

**Question:** /var is mounted twice, is this normal for a system that uses docker?

"df -m | grep var" only shows it mounted at /var.

Versions are: RHEL 7.2 Maipo, docker-engine-1.12.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64 and docker-engine-selinux-1.12.1-1.el7.centos.noarch.

---

**UPDATE**: Maybe normal? Can someone confirm? From OS perspective the two RW mounted FS doesn't look so OK.

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16884

*"This should not be an issue. /var/lib/docker/devicemapper is a bind mount onto itself. "*

Comment: I was wondering the same, my `df -ah` output shows my var drive, `/dev/mapper/vga-var`, is mapped to both `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper` and `/var`. While `lsblk` shows only the latter mapping. Weirdly the thin volume pool, `/dev/mapper/vga-var`, for my docker container(s) is not mapped anywhere at all, though I never set a line for it in `/etc/fstab`, since the docker device mapper notes don't mention to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Got the following info:

> The device mapper mounts differently to the rest of the var directory
>   so you are all good.
>
> That is expected behaviour

Hopefully this is OK then, thanks.